# Joining MP3 files losslessly

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, command-line, mp3

I have a bunch of MP3 files and I have their paths grouped in a text file.  Is it possible to join the relevant MP3 files based on the paths in the text file?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/20514/18665

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use `cat`:

```
$ cat example1 example 2 > output
```

or

```
$ cat example* > output
```

This will join any two files together - not sure what it will do to the ID3 metadata though.

Comment: This produces non standard MP3 files, i.e. the ID3 tags are getting ruined.  How do I correct the tags after using this method?

Comment: You would need to remove *all* metadata before catting.

Comment: How do you remove all the meta data?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of tool: `mpgtx` and `quelcom`.

You can see their descriptions through any package manager, for example:

```
apt-cache show mpgtx quelcom
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use these.  I have tried man, but there is not example usage section.

Comment: qmp3join: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/qmp3join.1.html

Basic usage is: qmp3join -o output.mp3 file1 file2...

It should be possible to automate the list of files based on the text file.

Comment: @Jonathon: `(IFS=$'\n'; qmp3join -o output.mp3 $(cat list.txt))` will pass each line of list.txt as a parameter. (`$''` is bash syntax, but you can do the same in other shells.)  The IFS change is necessary for any filenames that might contain spaces (which is common for music), otherwise it's not needed.

Comment: @Roger Pate: `$()`, without double quotes, already removes newlines, and `cat` is not needed: `qmp3join -o output.mp3 $(< list.txt)`

Comment: @enzotib: As I said, the change in IFS is necessary with a list.txt that contains one filename per line *and where the filenames contain spaces.*  Using cat or < is just personal preference here.

Comment: @Roger Pate: ok, I missed the spaces thing, but cat or < is not only matter of personale preferences, because with cat one spawn a further unnecessary process that can be avoided.

Comment: @enzotib: *Here* it is personal preference, as this will be run manually and rarely (not that another process often matters).  I trust anyone in a situation where that matters to know enough to look for and change it themselves, and don't mention the difference unless I'm teaching someone how to deal with that situation; instead sticking to more familiar syntax like "cat file" and "command < redirect".

Comment: @Roger Pate: btw, it works also without IFS and using double quotes: "$(< list.txt)"

Comment: @enzotib: No, it doesn't work: http://codepad.org/HyTzKvoI (showargs is my program to print each argument).  Did you test with a single-line file?

Comment: @Roger Pate: I don't know what your showargs do, but for me it works, also for a single line file

Comment: @enzotib: Note "$(...)" is a single argument, even if there are multiple lines, and this definitely does not work.  I don't know of any packaged program that does showarg's (very simple) job, that's why I [wroite it](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/104d8782bb83/python/showargs.py).

Comment: @Roger Pate: ok, i'm convinced (this is my showargs: http://pastebin.ca/1972596), sorry to take your time.

Comment: @enzotib: No problem; I really wish there was an easier solution than changing IFS.  You should post that showargs [as an answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/9336/1273). :)

Comment: Can someone please post the final answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally liked `mp3wrap` because it is more powerful and the size of the final file is three times less then the file merged with `cat` command.