# How can I make Rhythmbox display the correct time length of a concatenated .mp3 file?

Tags: vlc, rhythmbox, mp3

I used the tool [mp3wrap](http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/) to concatenate multiple .mp3 files into one. When playing the resulting file in VLC, the time length is shown correctly. Rhythmbox, however, only displays the time length of the first concatenated track.

Does someone know how I can make Rhythmbox display the length of the entire concatenated file?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration field is held locally in a file called `rhythmdb.xml` found in `~/.local/share/rhythmbox`

It is not updated if you just play a track.

To force rhythmbox to re-read the track and update rhythmdb.xml you need to ensure rhythmbox is watching for new or changed files:

[image]

Restart rhythmbox and rhythmbox should after a while update the track information being displayed.

You can also force a update by changing the timestamp of the audio track

```
cd ~/Music/youralbum
touch *.mp3
```

If after the above it still doesnt recognise the duration change then this is actually a gstreamer bug/or a bug in mp3wrap.  Gstreamer is the library that actually reads/writes audio tracks - not rhythmbox itself.

Gstreamer is  dependent on reading the ID3 info - if its not in the expected location then it will only pick out the information it can find.

Comment: Thank you @fossfreedom! Watching my library was enabled. I also touched the file again. But the length is still displayed wrongly. Thus, would you suggest me to file a bug against Gstreamer?

Comment: @orschiro - yep - give that a try.  However - try this answer as well - they say that the timestamp using mp3wrap could be wrong.  http://askubuntu.com/a/504794/14356

Comment: That is useful to know. Thank you @fossfreedom. However, mp3wrap does the handling of many files better. I can use `*.mp3` whereas for ffmpeg I need to name all files individually.