# How to download an entire YouTube playlist as a single mp3 file?

Tags: youtube

What are recommended solutions to download an entire YouTube playlist as a single `.mp3` file? I open to solutions other than `youtube-dl`.

Comment: Dear @Ev1l0rd, I am open to solutions other than `youtube-dl`.

Comment: What works, that works. There is no reason `youtube-dl` isn't a good solution. The reason there aren't any other solutions is that they are unnecessary because a perfectly usable tool already exists.

Comment: Another interesting option to look at is [alltomp3-cli](https://github.com/AllToMP3/alltomp3-cli). It aims to provide `deb` packages for easier installation in the near future.

Comment: To reopen reviewer: This question is not the same as and requires at least one additional step compared to the supposed duplicate link. See [my answer](/a/742111) for an example.

Comment: So, a combination of the current dupe and https://askubuntu.com/q/20507? Can someone edit the dupe list here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download playlists with `youtube-dl` in MP3 format as described in [how to download playlist from youtube-dl?](/q/564567/175814), e. g.:

```sh
youtube-dl -cix --audio-format mp3 -o '%(playlist_title)-%(playlist_id) - %(playlist_index) - %(title)-%(id).%(ext)' -- 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLttJ4RON7sleuL8wDpxbKHbSJ7BH4vvCk'
```

You can then use FFmpeg to concatenate those files:

```sh
printf "file '%s'\n" *.mp3 | ffmpeg -f concat -i - -codec copy all.mp3
```

It's a little more difficult with Avconv since it doesn't support the `concat` format:

```sh
avconv -i "concat:$(printf '%s|' *.mp3 | head -c -1)" -codec copy all.mp3
```

Comment: Isn't it necessary to use `--yes-playlist` option?

Comment: I tried those commands while writing the answer and they work as expected

Comment: Is it worthwhile to add `--audio-quality xx` to the youtube-dl commandline?

Comment: `youtube-dl` downloads the best quality by default. It is up to you if you want to specify the quality

Answer (score 1):

If you download each individual video as an `.mp3` you can just run this command to combine them:

```
cat 1.mp3 2.mp3 3.mp3 4.mp3 [and so on] > combined.mp3
```

Comment: Have you ever done this before and were you able to then play the `combined.mp3` without issue?

Comment: Yes, I do this all the time.