# Concatenate mp3 files via CLI "the right way"

Tags: command-line, mp3

I am looking for a simple, clean, robust solution to concatenate mp3 files.

I am aware of mp3wrap, but its concatenation seems oriented for a different job: easily splitting afterwards. That means that some players don't read track length correctly.

We could use `cat`, but is seems risky, as it probably messes with the metadata.

One could use ffmpeg: https://askubuntu.com/a/504794 . This has two downsides: one, it is complex, and two, ffmpeg is no longer supported.

One could use `sox`, but, in my tests, it  seems very slow. Perhaps it is re-encoding the whole thing, and would be suitable to small jobs (I am trying to concatenate a 7 hour audiobook)

The best answer so far seems to be to download an external utility: http://mulholland.xyz/dev/mp3cat/. Wondering if there is nothing in the repositories to replace that?

I am wondering if there is no simple utility, similar to mp3wrap, that concatenates mp3 files into a "correct" mp3, with "correct" length, available on the repositories.

(btw, I am aware of question [Concatenating several .mp3 files into one .mp3](https://askubuntu.com/q/20507), but wanted to ask specifically for a more clean solution. I hope this is not considered a straight up duplicate and, in any case, that we can leave this question open to find a better solution, if only to close it later and post the good solution to that original question.)

Comment: Have you looked into using `avconv` (which replaces `ffmpeg`)?

Comment: Not yet, no. Hoping for a simpler solution. Have had some bad experiences converting video and audio in the past ^^'

Comment: sox does a reasonable job, have you experimented with this? BTW FFmpeg is supported under newer versions of Ubuntu while avconv is now deprecated...

Comment: Glad I did not bother to learn avconv,then :)

Comment: Sox seems way to slow for me... I am joining a 7 hour audiobook. It it decoding and re-encoding the whole thing?

Comment: So far the best thing I have is to download mp3cat (http://mulholland.xyz/dev/mp3cat/). My only objection to it is that it is not on Ubuntu's repositories