# Is there a simple GUI-based program available to join/combine mp3 files?

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Joining MP3 files losslessly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9168/joining-mp3-files-losslessly)

I have an audio book on CD which when ripped to my Hard Drive has multiple chapters as individual mp3 files. Is there a simple program that could combine them all, in order, into one big file?

I'm aware of Audacity but it seemed to involve a fair amount of cutting and pasting to get the job done, bearing in mind there are 30-40 chapters! (though of course I may have been doing it the long winded way!).

There appears to be command line options but I'm not all that confident in using them. so not all that sure of using the possible solutions in this question: [Joining MP3 files losslessly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9168/joining-mp3-files-losslessly)

Comment: I saw that thread but didn't think it really answered my question, as it asked for a way to join mp3's based on their path in a text file. I just wanted to know if there was a simple program to do this?

Comment: the cat solution is not dependent on paths - nor is mp3wrap.  You could use cat filename* > output if all files are in the same folder.  If none of the solutions are suitable for you, please add to your question a link to that question, what you have tried and what is different in your circumstance that the solutions there do no apply to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know h to use the commandline, then this seems to be an easy solution:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/qmp3join.1.html

The necessary packages are available here (though I haven't tried them out):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/quelcom

Comment: I think posting solution which you do not know would not help the person or the forum. I would recommend editing it to make it more useful. This could become a downvote mine . :)

Comment: huh? Downvoted because I didn't try out the solution? Wth? The url I posted holds enough information to try it out and it sounds as if *could* help with the problem. Fact is, a lot of the answers here are suggestions for *possible* solutions that may or may not work for one user or another. Judging by your critera, a lot of answers would have to be downvoted.

Comment: The idea is to have suggestions which would work. I could easily said why not do a apt-cache search join mp3. This is not useful as one could just as much ask him to do a google search. The idea is to have a more conclusive help which can be stored for posterity.